# What's the AC meaning there?

Tags: huawei

What's the AC meaning there, see the bellow snapshot.

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Comment: What is the link to where you found the picture or took the snapshot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why they use the **AC** label. It is an OLT (Optical Line Termination). The OLT provides two main functions:

1. Performs conversion between the electrical signals used by the service provider's equipment and the fiber optic signals used by the passive optical network.
2. Coordinates the multiplexing between the conversion devices on the other end of that network (called either optical network terminals or optical network units).

Check this **[link](https://www.slideshare.net/CarlosRomero110/huawei-network-icon-database-v2)** where the same icon is referenced to an specific Huawei model and this [brochure](http://www.huaweigpon.cz/wp-content/uploads/Huawei-SmartAX-MA5600T-Series-OLT-Brochure.pdf) with specifications of the device